# deploying sandbox to production

Tags: deployment

while i am deploying sandbox to production  i created  outbound change sets in sandbox respectively to create inbound change sets in production too?
and my role is system administrator.

Every time i upload outbound change sets same message is showing--"This organization isn't authorized to upload change sets to other organizations. For authorization, contact the deployment connections administrators on the organizations where you want to upload changes".

Answer (score 2):

You have to initially configure your Deployment Settings. In your Sandbox, go to Setup > Quick Find *Deployment Status* > Deployment Status, and click Edit next to Production, and allow outbound connections. Then, in your Production org, go to the same place, click Edit next to your Sandbox, and allow incoming connections. See [Deployment Connections for Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_connection.htm&language=en) and the related help topics for more details.

Comment: hi sfdcfox, i checked in deployment status but its showing "no records to display"

Comment: @Rajesh It states you have to be logged in to both orgs at the same time. It's always worked for me. Note that you can't link a stand-alone Developer Edition to a Sandbox or Production-- they need to have a Production-Sandbox relationship to begin with (the Sandbox must have been made from that Production org, or must be a Sandbox related to another Sandbox through the same Production org).

Comment: @Rajesh if the sandboxes are not connected to each other you cant deploy the outbound change set. If the two environments are not connected you need to use
- a migration tool (ant or eclipse)
- or if what you are deploying is all "new elements", you can use unmanaged packages that is more userfriendly.. You can use the unmanaged packages only for new elements, which are not already present on the target environment.

Comment: @sfdcfox the deployment done successfully previously. But they gave me new credentials to me.

Comment: @klodj i don't knowledge on migration tool..i want to deploy a simple custom object...please let me know

Comment: @Rajesh oki, then for a custom object you can use unmanaged packages.  To do so you have: to go to:
=> setup => search packages => new... follow the instructions to create the package. In the End you will obtain a link that allow you to install it in any other environment. 
Anyway this is not te best practice for the develop-deployment process. For future changes this will not work. For future changes you have to ask an sandbox connected to production or the target sandbox.

Comment: @klodj thanking you lot.....it works..further i will try to connect orgs...

Answer (score 0):

Go to target org.

Setup --> Deploy --> Deployment Setting , click Edit your source sandbox.

Check if Allow Inbound Changes is checked.